# List Column that auto-increments from 100,000

Tags: list, custom-list

One of our employees wants to have a column in his list that autoincrement from 100,000. I tried to use "ID" column, then create a "calculated" column that adds 100,000. That didn't help; id populates after item is generated. Then I found an article telling me to use sharepoint workflow. But I can't seem to find where it is. The article also suggests to use Sharepoint Designer, but that thing hasn't been upgraded since 2013.

Does anyone know how to generate a column like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can achieve this using the SharePoint designer workflow.

Here are the steps to create an auto-incrementing number field in a SharePoint list designer workflow:

1. Create a new column, such as : **Increment Number** in issue list with
   Number type. Make this column hidden in a view.
2. Create another column, such as : **Issue No**. in issue list with Formula type and add the following formula = “100000” & [Increment Number]. This Column will show the increment items’ numbers in the list.
3. Open SharePoint designer, create new list workflow (for issues list).
4. Add a workflow action: “Update list Item” >> Current Item >> Add >> Set this field to your Target field (Increment Number), set value from Current Item:ID field.
5. Set the workflow start option to “Start Workflow automatically when an item is created”.
6. Save and Publish the workflow.

For detailed steps refer the below:

[How to Create an Auto-Incrementing Number Field in a SharePoint List](https://www.epmpartners.com.au/blog/how-to-create-an-auto-incrementing-number-field-in-a-sharepoint-list/)

[Auto Serial Number in SharePoint New Form](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/auto-serial-number-new-form-sharepoint/)

Comment: It did work, but the list requires a page refresh to see the changed value. Is that correct?

Comment: Ohh.. I think in that case, we can redirect to same item URL after updating the field using the Redirect URL action in the same workflow... that will solve the issue.

Comment: Actually I was wrong. It does update automatically. No refresh required. But it's not instant sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for keeping the community updated :-)